Is it possible to overnight at DEN for a early-morning flight out?
I'm supposed to fly out of Denver International (DEN) very early on Wednesday (departure at 5:00 am.) I'm currently in central downtown, near the convention center. Usually when I fly out of DEN, I leave 2 hours ahead of departure or thereabouts, depending on traffic conditions, rush hour, etc. For this flight, I was planning on leaving between 3-3:30 am.
However, right now they're calling for freezing rain and snow throughout the night before (Tuesday to Wednesday). This is making me nervous about the commute since I'll be taking rideshare or taxi.
Is it possible to go through security the day before (or possibly at ~1am right before security shuts down for the night) and spend the intervening hours in the secured area? My flight is Southwest, so it'll likely either be the A or C concourses. To be clear -- this is not a connection, I'm originating in Denver.

Sleeping in Airports is a very good resource https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/denver-airport-guide.htm

Do you have any checked bags?

Or book a room at one of the hotels right there.

@JonCuster There is a hotel at the airport, I hadn't thought of that.

@NicolasFormichella The question is less "can I spend the night in the terminal" and more "can I cross security potentially the day before". The Denver page is no longer up to date, there's more than just North and South security now (and I don't think South is 24 hour anymore.) I know that I can overnight in terminal B -- my sister did that a few months back.

What I also know is that there's no actual place to bum around in the Jeppesen terminal before security, especially with the construction going on.

@jcaron Yes I will be checking 1 bag. So I guess that complicates things based on when bag drop opens... :(

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas which is well hidden but seems to be at best 4 hours before departure https://support.southwest.com/helpcenter/s/article/How-long-before-my-flights-departure-time-can-I-check-bags “Checked baggage will be accepted at the airport ticket counter or curbside check-in locations (where available) no earlier than four hours ahead of flight departure time.” So 1am in your case (if they are even open at that time)

You know about the train (RTD A line) as another option, right? The first departure of the day from Union Station is 3:00 AM. I don't know how much it's subject to disruption from weather, but probably no worse than the roads.

And I suppose you also know that you can freely go to the B concourse even if that's not where your flight is. The train between them is entirely post security.

@NateEldredge My experience with RTD during snow storms is that the trains actually will get shut down due to track icing before the buses stop running. That said, that's what has historically happened on the light rail lines; not sure if the rail line is more resilient. Since this particular storm is calling for freezing rain prior to snow, the icing would be a concern here.

South security is indeed no longer 24 hour, it opens at 3 am and closes at 1 am. (Contrary to sleeping in airports, which does not make submitting up to date information easy.) The southwest bag drop and desks are not manned starting some time before the last flight of the previous night leaves according to the SW employee working bag drop this morning. She couldn't give me a straight answer about whether I would've been able to drop my bag the night before.
